# Handling too many geopackages in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geopackage

I have been using this 3.24 for a month or more. Now that I am using it, I have created every project using this one.

I am facing an issue with this version (not sure if this problem is only for this version or all the versions)

I have 400+ geo-package ( I know it’s too many layers but I can't do anything to reduce it; instead, I can do more). Now, this can't handle too many layers of geo-packages. It crashes whenever I try to open those packages and render. Are there any limitations on how many boxes can be opened in qgis?

If there is o limitation, can anyone please suggest how I can handle all of those layers of geo-packages and use them for my project?

I am sharing my PC configuration:
i5, 12GB RAM, 250GB SSD and 2 GB MX110 GFX.

Comment: You have only one layer per geopackage?

Comment: No. Too many of them. I just made a group of at lest 600 geo-packeges! All of them are line (network) between point to point.

Comment: I would clarify the terminology. One .gpkg file is a GeoPackage. One GeoPackage can have several spatial tables which appear as layers when they are opened with QGIS. You case seem to be that you have a GeoPackage file with more that 600 tables and QGIS cannot render your data if you open all 600 tables as layers into your QGIS project. Is this right?

Comment: @user30184 
Maybe I messed up something. Will you please look at this screenshot and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify, it's about 1200*, not 600

Comment: I can't see a screenshot. Like this, its difficult to help.

Comment: @Babel 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJKkL8rwHNFreBeCQVBjH20DwVdX2cDJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you are saying that you have 1200 separate map layers, then I suggest that you rethink your methodology. That's really unreasonable. You could, for example, add a column `code` to all layers, and enter the code for each, separately, then merge them all into a single line layer in a single gpkg.

Comment: @Micha Thank you for your suggesion, but I need all separate lines between two nodes. If I merge them, it will not work for my project.

Comment: My suggestion was to merge the files, not the lines. You can give each line its own code to keep them separate, but all in one file. (Think of a road network with thousands of roads all in one layer)

Comment: @Micha Thank you. I have done that and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot just show that you have a lot of gpkg. As I understand, you have only one layer per gpkg. As a start point, I suggest you to have one gpkg with multiple layers!

Comment: Thank you I will try to do that.